# How to storing unsent Attachment as message draft

Tags: getstream-chat

I am follow getstream.io to implement storing unsent user's messages as drafts, so I would like to implement it for attachment too, but I cannot see it in getstream's documents.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific on how you are trying to store the messages? Also, which guide are you following to store unsent user messages?

Also, it would be helpful to know which SDK you are working with.

Happy to help, just need a bit more information. :)

Comment: @StefanBlos I follow this document to store unsent message: https://getstream.io/chat/docs/sdk/react/guides/persist-input-text-in-localstorage/